# How do I add additional packages in scope for Spacemacs in Nixos?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, nixos

I'm trying to setup Spacemacs on my Nixos system. I installed Emacs using the `nixos.emacs` package. One of the spacemacs layers that I'm trying to install requires the command-line program `aclocal`, but it can't find it on my system.

I believe one solution would be to just add the Nix package that contains `aclocal` (I believe it's `autoconf`) to my `environment.systemPackages`. However, I don't like this solution because it adds the `autoconf` package to my global scope. I would rather that *only* Emacs have access to `autoconf`, so that (1) it keeps my global list of packages clean, and (2) I don't accidentally delete it in the future, if I forget why I installed it.

Is there a way to do this in Nixos? I think it might involve overriding some attributes of the `emacs` derivation.

**EDIT:** To be clear, I don't need the `autoconf` package to be an input to building Emacs---I want Emacs to be built exactly as it currently is---but I want the `autoconf` library to be accessible to any of the binaries, and the child processes, of `emacs`, `emacsclient`, etc. when I run them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can wrap `emacs` binary with `wrapProgram` and prefix the `$PATH` with list of packages you want (you will need to add `makeWrapper` to `buildInputs`). eg.

```
postInstall = ''
  wrapProgram "$out/bin/emacs" --prefix PATH : "${autoconf}/bin"
'';
```

an example from `nixpkgs` would be [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/networking/cluster/kubernetes/default.nix#L50) but there are more examples (`grep wrapProgram pkgs -R | grep '\-\-prefix PATH'`).